# La différence d'usage entre « quand bien même » et « même si »

Tags: temps-grammatical, conjonctions

> **Quand bien même** il **aurait** raison, je veux qu'on y aille voir les choses par nous-mêmes.

Vis-à-vis de :

> **Même s**'il **a** raison, je veux qu'on y aille voir les choses par nous-mêmes.

Si ce n'est que les deux expressions ont un sens voisin, je n'y connais pas grand-chose là-dessus. Avec le recul, la plupart du temps où j'ai entendu la locution « quand bien même » utilisée, elle était suivie du conditionnel (même si ce n'est pas forcément le cas).

La conjonction « même si », en revanche, a tendance à être suivie de l'indicatif. Ce qui m'amène à me demander si « même si » réfère à une possibilité qui peut se révéler vraie avec une chance sur deux, alors que « quand bien même » réfère plutôt à une hypothèse nettement moins probable.

Comment: en style plus soutenu, on écrirait « quand même il aurait raison », l'ajout du « bien » étant un peu lourdaud et (à vérifier) plus récent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pour moi, **quand bien même il aurait raison** laisse très peu de place au fait qu'il puisse avoir raison. Il a probablement tort, et quand bien même il aurait raison, ça ne changerait rien.

Alors que **même s'il a raison** montre une plus grande possibilité qu'il ait raison, voire dans certains cas indique clairement qu'il a effectivement raison, mais que ça ne change rien. Il a raison, mais même s'il a raison, c'est trop tard. Je ne pense pas que *quand bien même* puisse s'employer lorsqu'on sait qu'il a raison (il semble devoir être suivi obligatoirement du conditionnel : http://www.academie-francaise.fr/catherine-b-france).

Évidemment, selon l'utilisation, le ton employé, l'ajout d'autres mots qui viendront préciser la probabilité, les sens peuvent être plus ou moins proches.