# The function of "que" as a conjunction, compared to using "et" or "mais"

Tags: conjonctions

> La ville n’est ***pas encore*** remise de la tragédie qui l’a frappée, **que** l’ombre d’une nouvelle guerre plane ***déjà*** sur elle.

What does the conjunction "que" denote here that "et" or "mais" does not? I wonder if the phrases "pas encore" and "déjà" have something to do with it?

> {vs}: La ville n’est pas encore remise de la tragédie qui l’a frappée, **et / mais** l’ombre d’une nouvelle guerre plane déjà sur elle.

Comment: Are you sure about the comma in the middle of the sentence? It looks weird.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Yes, there is indeed a comma there.

Comment: I think this comma is a mistake, where does this citation come from?

Comment: I would tend to understand this « que » as "when".

Comment: @AnneAunyme Hi. Actually, I don't remember where exactly I got this from, but it was meant to be written French. I suppose it is unusual to use this "que" construction in spoken French?

Comment: Not very unusual, except in oral language. But you'll find this written.

Comment: @Alone-zee: I suspect this comes from a newspaper, and French journalists have a reputation of making many mistakes (it can be explained by the fact they have to write a lot and quickly)

Comment: I wonder if this sin't the same sort of slightly superfluous *que* seen [in this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26925/926).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using "et" or "mais", the two parts of the proposition have an equivalent level of importance. With this use of "que" the first part is a context for the next part. What follows "que" carries the factual statement of the sentence, which is to be read with the context in mind.

The sentence starts by reminding about the context:

> La ville ne s'est pas encore remise de la tragédie qui l'a frappée.

And then describes a new event, that is reinforced by the context:

> L'ombre d'une nouvelle guerre plane déjà sur elle.

You are supposed to empathize with the inhabitants of these city who just went to a tragedy and are already preparing for an other one.

You can notice that in this particular sentence the "new event" is not really an event, just a situation. This mistake from the writer is very common, particularly in newspapers.

The general meaning would be similar with "et":

> La ville n’est pas encore remise de la tragédie qui l’a frappée et l’ombre d’une nouvelle guerre plane déjà sur elle.

But the meaning that the past tragedy makes the present menace even more terrible is lost.

With "mais" the sentence would oppose two things with a similar tone: it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Mais grammaticalement ? quelle est la fonction de _que_, et quelle est la nature de la proposition qu'il introduit ? (je demande en français parce que je ne suis pas sûr de savoir traduire la question correctement en anglais)

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO: je ne suis pas sur de moi sur ce point, donc je préfère éviter de dire des bêtises. L'OP n'ayant pas manifesté d'intéret particulier pour l'aspect grammatical de la phrase j'ai essayé de répondre en expliquant le sens.

Comment: Oui je comprends bien,  la question me parait intéressante et je ne sais pas y répondre non plus. Si quelqu'un nous lit et a la réponse, je suis preneur.

Comment: Si on réfléchit à d'autres exemples de construction identique, on s'aperçoit que l'utilisation de la préposition *que* introduit un élément temporel, dans le sens où l'évènement n°2 succède de près à l'évènement n°1. "A peine le président  eut-il pris la parole que des cris fusèrent dans l'assemblée". "Nous venions tout juste d'arriver qu'il se mit à tomber des cordes".

Comment: @Jaxx, c'est vrai (si l'on fait abstraction de la nature de `que`qui n'est pas une préposition) mais pas seulement, comme le montre l'exemple : _Le voudrait-il, qu'il ne le pourrait pas_ (Balzac). @Anne_Aunyme : Grammaticalement, nous avons ici une proposition principale précédée de le conjonction de subordination `que`, et une proposition subordonnée conjonctive placée avant la principale. D'après _Grammaire française de E Aumeunier et D. Zevaco (1955)_, `Cette construction permet de mettre en valeur la pensée exprimée par la subordonnée`.